# (Done) Reopen: What if I'm a better developer than my Team Leader?

Tags: discussion, reopen-request

This question

[What if I'm a better developer than my Team Leader?](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/q/119757/9549)

asks

> So what if I'm a better developer than my Team Leader? Should I try to "take his place" as a team leader?

which was closed as asking for advice on a specific choice. I will make the case that this is not what the question is asking at all.

The question is asking

1. Does the Team Lead need to be the best craftsman in the team
2. Do good craftsmen make good leaders of same <sup>*(which not entirely the same as above)*</sup>
3. Should I try to take the lead's place if the lead is not a good craftsman
4. How can I deal with my team lead's poor craftsmanship (frame challenge)

I would normally edit and vote to reopen, but this question can be saved in multiple ways so I thought I should put it to you first. I think it's very much worth saving (attested to by an excellent answer), so what's the best way to go about it?

Comment: I think it should be re-opened. I am not even sure it needs much of an edit TBH.

Comment: Just need to re-word the parts where it says "should I" I am not a great editor, but someone with more experience could do it for sure

Comment: @SaggingRufus it already has some good answers... will take a shot at the edit

Comment: Those are 4 questions. #1 has been asked before. #2 is largely useless, you might as well ask if fishermen make good laywers. The answer "it's a separate skillset" is the answer to #1. The "if the lead.." part of #3 is basically answered by #1 as well. #4 has promise but would have to be worded very well to avoid domain-specific answers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Final reopen vote cast and the question is now open.

Answer (score 2):

Took an edit to the question. Removed the "should I" parts, and reworded some of the questions asked so they are more on-topic.

Also completely replaced the tags used, as they were not closely related to the content of the post. Casted the 2nd vote...

Comment: Edit looks good to me (currently 3 re-open votes)

Comment: Currently 4 votes